# Writing a Spring Application context unit test without including test dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to write a junit test which tests the application configuration of my spring boot application. This test is meant to catch any runtime failures on app startup due to any number of reasons.

Recently, I noticed that this test was giving a false positive and was passing during mvn clean install, but was failing when I actually started the application locally.

My assumption is that the required dependencies which were not present at production runtime, *were* present in the test scope of the UT (hidden transitively through some other test deps).

My question is, is there a way to tell a context test to only pull in compile/runtime/provided scope dependencies and ignore test scoped dependencies so these application context tests don't falsely pass?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(
        locations = {"classpath:application-test.properties", "classpath:feature.properties"})
@BootstrapWith(Bootstrapper.class)
public class ApplicationContextTest {

    @Autowired private ApplicationMain appMain;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        assertNotNull(appMain);
        // do some other checks
    }
}
```

Besides the Bootstrapper, all of my classes in the test are production classes (i.e. production configuration class, production spring application, etc). But because the test needs to actually be placed in the java test dir, it still pulls in test scoped dependencies automatically. The Bootstrapper class only serves as a wrapper to add FullyQualifiedBeanNameGenerator to the spring context.